# AWS: signing key for Signature Version 4: how to do it using Web Cryptography API?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, cryptojs, webcrypto-api

For my webapp I want to communicate with DynamoDB directly from a client, without intermediate API Gateway and Lambda. And I do not want to use JS SDK just for a few http calls and keys signing. I stumbled upon with [key signing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html) - examples given for a few languages but not for native js module [Crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/subtle). Example using `crypto-js`:

```
Crypto.HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
```

I tried:

```
const kSecret  = '41575334774a616c725855746e46454d492f4b374d44454e472b62507852666943594558414d504c454b4559',
    dateStamp = '20120215'


function _binaryToHex(array) {
    return array.map(b => ('00' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}


/**
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey
 */
async function _importKey(keyDataArrayBuffer) {
    return crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'raw',
        keyDataArrayBuffer,
        {'name': 'hmac', 'hash': {'name': 'SHA-256'}},
        false,
        ['sign']);
}

const kDate = _binaryToHex(
    Array.from(
        new Uint8Array(
            await crypto.subtle.sign(
                'HMAC',
                await _importKey(
                    new TextEncoder().encode(kSecret)
                ),
                new TextEncoder().encode(dateStamp)
            )
        )
    )
);
console.log(kDate);
/* Must be
 * '969fbb94feb542b71ede6f87fe4d5fa29c789342b0f407474670f0c2489e0a0d'
 */
```

But output not the same as in example.

Comment: if you're exposing your key in a client application then just make dynamo publicly accessible. you're wasting your time on pseudo security

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that client has a user key from Cognito - I am not exposing key from my AWS account.

Comment: cognito id tokens and aws secret keys aren't the same thing. you can't use them interchangeably.

Comment: Using `id_token` from Cognito I am getting `IdentityId`, using that I am getting temporal `Credentials` for that user with `SecretKey` and `AccessKeyId` inside, valid for one hour.

Comment: Again, these are not the same thing as an AWS IAM secret key / access key pair.  You cannot use Cognito to authenticate for dynamoDB.  You can use it to authenticate for API Gateway.

Comment: Hey, look at this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups

Comment: guess i was mistaken then, I'll be interested if you get this to work. Have you confirmed that it works using the SDK?

Comment: Yes, I tried this example from article https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-angular-cognito-sample

Comment: good luck then, AWS signing is a pain. the SDK isn't that heavy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, I must be attentive and thoughtful - here simple bug - input key `kSecret` already encoded to the hexadecimal - but must be original human-readable value for

`new TextEncoder().encode('AWS4wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY')`